# Почему во второй функции не работает цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, csv, dict

Считываю csv файл

```
csvfile = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=simbol)
// все отлично <csv.DictReader object at 0x03DA2590>

#эта функция работает отлично
def strategy(csvfile):    
    for line in csvfile:
        cash = cash + int(line['price'])
    return cash

#эта функция перестает работать
def strategy2(csvfile):    
    for line in csvfile:
        cash = cash + int(line['price'])
    return cash

print('1: ',strategy(csvfile))
print('2: ',strategy2(csvfile))
//1: выводит нужную сумму
//2: ничего не выводит
```

почему во второй функции не идет цикл for in для csvfile? если поставить в начало цикла print, ничего не выводит.

Comment: Пробовали использовать функции в обратном порядке? Сначала вывести результат 2й функции, потом - первой. Возможно, проблема в указателе файла, и его нужно перемещать на начало файла после выполнения функции. Если это так, то в случае вышеуказанной проверки функция `strategy2` сработает, а `strategy` выдаст ошибку, т.к. теперь `strategy2` выполняется первой

Comment: Если меняю их местами, да, вторая работает, а первая нет. А каким образом переместить  указатель на начало  файла?

Comment: нашел, ответ file_stream.seek(0)

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на мою проблему. Объект возращаемый csv.DictReader обнуляется после первого использования.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
print(reader) # Вот тут все в порядке, reader не пустой

def any_func():
   print(reader) # А вот тут reader уже пустой!!!?
```

Решил проблему преобразованием reader в list сразу после создания:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
list_reader = list(reader)
print(list_reader) 

def any_func():
   print(list_reader)
```

Comment: Ну, правильнее сказать не обнуляется, а исчерпывается. Это итератор, который можно перебрать только один раз.